# Work with elm and select

Tags: elm

I try to understand how elm works with a custom example.

```
durationOption duration =
  option [value (toString duration) ] [ text (toString duration)]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  Html.div []
    [ h2 [] [ text "Month selector"]
    , select []
      (List.map durationOption [1..12])    
    ]
```

It's an easy example to work with a select. I would like, each time I change the month value it multiplies to value by 10 for example. According to the documentation there is not events like `onChange` or `onSelect`, do I have to create mine with [on](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.2/Html-Events#on) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

UPDATE: `onInput` works, see another answer below with 0.19 working code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41516493/540810

Yes, you will need to use `on` to handle the change event. If you look at the [source for other event handlers](https://github.com/elm-lang/html/blob/1.0.0/src/Html/Events.elm) built into Elm, like [`onClick`](https://github.com/elm-lang/html/blob/1.0.0/src/Html/Events.elm#L48), you'll see that they are all built using the `on` function.

Here's an example that is using [targetValueIntParse](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra/2.2.0/Html-Events-Extra#targetValueIntParse) from [elm-community/html-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra) for turning the string value from the option into an int.

Updated to Elm-0.18

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Json
import String
import Html.Events.Extra exposing (targetValueIntParse)


main =
    beginnerProgram { model = { duration = 1 }, view = view, update = update }


durationOption duration =
    option [ value (toString duration) ] [ text (toString duration) ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Html.div []
        [ h2 [] [ text "Month selector" ]
        , select [ on "change" (Json.map SetDuration targetValueIntParse) ]
            (List.map durationOption (List.range 1 12))
        , div [] [ text <| "Selected: " ++ (toString model.duration) ]
        ]


type Msg
    = SetDuration Int


type alias Model =
    { duration : Int }


update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetDuration val ->
            { model | duration = val }
```

You can run this example in browser https://runelm.io/c/ahz

Comment: thanks for your response. I need more skills to undertand whats append in this piece of code.

Comment: Why `onChange` doesn't exist in the standard library?

Comment: Don't forget that you can use `Html.Attributes.selected = True` in the `option` element to make sure the chosen option is always appearing correctly in the select box.

Answer (score 43):

With Elm 0.18.0 + elm-lang/html 2.0.0, the `onInput` event (see code below) works ([see official elm examples](https://elm-lang.org/examples/forms)). (Also notice the difference in int range notation (`List.range 0 12` instead of `[0..12]`).

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)


main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    { model = model
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
  { duration : Int
  }


model : Model
model =
  Model 0



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = SetDuration String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    SetDuration s ->
      let result =
        String.toInt s
      in
        case result of
          Ok v ->
            { model | duration = v }
            
          Err message ->
            model


-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ select [ onInput SetDuration ]
             (List.range 0 12 |> List.map intToOption)
    , div [] [ text <| "Selected: " ++ (toString model.duration) ]         
    ]


intToOption : Int -> Html Msg
intToOption v =
  option [ value (toString v) ] [ text (toString v) ]
```

Comment: Is there a reason this shouldn't be marked as the answer?  Way less hassle.

Comment: not as cross-browser compatible at the moment as `onChange`, unfortunately.  http://caniuse.com/#search=oninput

Comment: Everything except Opera Mini? That's plenty compatible.

Comment: `onInput` doesn't fire for `select` in Internet Explorer, so compatibility is more limited than @RobertFischer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update for Elm 0.19:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Json
import String
import Html.Events.Extra exposing (targetValueIntParse)


main =
    Browser.sandbox { init = { duration = 1 }, view = view, update = update }


durationOption duration =
    option [ value (String.fromInt duration) ] [ text (String.fromInt duration) ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Html.div []
        [ h2 [] [ text "Month selector" ]
        , select [ on "change" (Json.map SetDuration targetValueIntParse) ]
            (List.map durationOption (List.range 1 12))
        , div [] [ text <| "Selected: " ++ (String.fromInt model.duration) ]
        ]


type Msg
    = SetDuration Int


type alias Model =
    { duration : Int }


update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetDuration val ->
            { model | duration = val }
```

Answer (score 1):

An example with `onInput` handler (you can also check the [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/4WYDLJPY8gDa1)):

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, select, option) import Html.Attributes exposing (value, selected) import Html.Events exposing (onInput) import Dict exposing (Dict)

type alias Model =
    { options : Dict Int (String, Bool)
    }


initialModel : Model initialModel =
    { options = Dict.fromList [(0, ("All time", False)), (1, ("One week", True)), (2, ("24h", False))] 
    }


type Msg
    = Select String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model update msg model =
    case msg of
        Select value ->
            case String.toInt value of
                Just selectedID ->
                    let
                        changeSelection id (label, _) =
                            if id == selectedID then
                                (label, True)
                            else
                                (label, False)
                    in
                    {model | options = Dict.map changeSelection model.options}

                Nothing ->
                    model



view : Model -> Html Msg view model =
    let
        toOption (id, (label, isSelected)) =
            option [value (String.fromInt id), selected isSelected] [text label]
    in
    div []
        [ select [onInput Select] (List.map toOption <| Dict.toList model.options)
        , div [] [text "DEBUG"]
        , div [] [text <| Debug.toString model.options]
        ]


main : Program () Model Msg main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with [Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/new) on Elm 0.19.0: https://ellie-app.com/58wGf2YsR9Ya1

Full code:

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Json
import String
import Html.Events.Extra exposing (targetValueIntParse)

main =
    Browser.sandbox { init = init, view = view, update = update }

init =
    { duration = 1 }

durationOption duration =
    option [ value (String.fromInt duration) ] [ text (String.fromInt duration) ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    Html.div []
        [ h2 [] [ text "Month selector" ]
        , select [ on "change" (Json.map SetDuration targetValueIntParse) ]
            (List.map durationOption (List.range 1 12))
        , div [] [ text <| "Selected: " ++ (String.fromInt model.duration) ]
        ]


type Msg
    = SetDuration Int


type alias Model =
    { duration : Int }


update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetDuration val ->
            { model | duration = val }
```